# Embedding base64 encodded image within angular 10 application

Tags: angular, html-encode

Below is the json retrieved from the API. How i can embed this content in a web page and display the image using Angular 9+

```
<div> 
<p>Some test content</p>   
<img alt="download" height="165" src="" width="306" http-src="lUxTgnFw9VSgBRT6YZQsfaREwG4tj+MXGW2ZjBwDEAZKxx888+65fWeu3IBnsHybs18oDLjDqBZtXAurQh5A7nhN9rfEVV3EWu3CwTrfA8T2nDKUq2AdY16+dgSS1z7htLGdH4MXNFI8/HatANnpNjp1HlPh2fkW/2+84MLLPJERQ1U5n/oXLjYiF9MSAyHnQotubWlr+fqwlNVcwNTX/+hkYB0EWdLffWNgfWXtNwr+0+ZwRVq3fw3ClNzv6e3xa0IDT93+SkiX8emnP7BgOqcKNP8TLmfShj5jmNGd8/pI7ioKJmi9MPdhHvE08842Y1pQvwSOVmhTcgiuZ/AMqMs/r4p0L0/GHlcdrgjlkn7CHU3XTo7x+3MTQ7X0HGdjouEfYWBFG97GE3SHre7Yzw==" http-src-type="view"/></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To render HTML in angular, you have to use `innerHTML`. So you will have:

```
<div [innerHTML]="response"></div>
```

But I think that you have to change the response. Add the **base64** string to image `src` instead of `http-src` and you also have to concatenate to this string `data:image/jpg;base64,`. And you will have
`<img src="data:image/jpg;base64, BASE64" />`. Otherwise, you have to alternate the response.

Comment: The issue is with embedding the image. HTML rendering is fine but the image is not displayed. It works fine with AngularJs when using ```.trustAsHtml```. Is there any alternative way without modifying the response?

Comment: The equivalent for `.trustAsHtml` in Angular2+ is `domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl()`. You can try to use this then.

Answer (score 0):

If you can edit the api response you can edit it like that:

```html
   <div> 
<p>Some test content</p>   
<img alt="download" height="165" width="306" [src]="data:image/jpg;base64,lUxTgnFw9VSgBRT6YZQsfaREwG4tj+MXGW2ZjBwDEAZKxx888+65fWeu3IBnsHybs18oDLjDqBZtXAurQh5A7nhN9rfEVV3EWu3CwTrfA8T2nDKUq2AdY16+dgSS1z7htLGdH4MXNFI8/HatANnpNjp1HlPh2fkW/2+84MLLPJERQ1U5n/oXLjYiF9MSAyHnQotubWlr+fqwlNVcwNTX/+hkYB0EWdLffWNgfWXtNwr+0+ZwRVq3fw3ClNzv6e3xa0IDT93+SkiX8emnP7BgOqcKNP8TLmfShj5jmNGd8/pI7ioKJmi9MPdhHvE08842Y1pQvwSOVmhTcgiuZ/AMqMs/r4p0L0/GHlcdrgjlkn7CHU3XTo7x+3MTQ7X0HGdjouEfYWBFG97GE3SHre7Yzw=="/></p>
</div>
```

and put it into ad [innerHTML]. it should work